# Which of the following android package is emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to setup react native without android studio by following [this](https://medium.com/@khairold/setting-up-react-native-on-linux-without-android-studio-a65f3e011bbb). Below are the packages that it asks me to install:

```
sudo /opt/android/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24"
```

But the problem is that it is also downloading emulator, which I don't want because I would be running on a real device( It is large as well). I am unable to identify which of the above package is leading to installation of emulator.

Can you please help me so that emulator is not downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked for it by dedicating some time, I have found that installing `build tools` will install emulator as well.